# jquery scroll inconsistent with breakpoint trigger

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to make text display at increments of 30px.

```
if (($('.browser-window').scrollTop()%30)==0){
        alert('should trigger');
}
```

At times, I scroll too fast and miss the scroll breakpoint (30,60,90). What is the best practice to make the scroll always trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a greater than comparison to catch the case where you never hit your number exactly.

Following is an example that keeps track of which breakpoints have been triggered so they only get triggered once each.

Before (outside) your `onScroll` event:

```
var num_triggers = 0;
```

In your `onScroll` event:

```
if ($('.browser-window').scrollTop() > 30 * (num_triggers + 1)){
        alert('triggered');
        num_triggers++;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I just had to change the breakpoint to 100px to make it fluid.